# SQL proc is not executing completely when I execute it using python

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, t-sql, spyder

I am trying to execute a sql proc using python and I notice that not the complete proc is getting executed. I am able to execute procs that contain only fewer lines of code without any issue but not lengthy procs (maybe 2/3rd of the proc gets executed).

Thanks in advance for the help.

```
import glob
import os
import shutil
import pandas as pd 
import pypyodbc as pydb

stmt = 'EXEC procname' 
conn = pydb.connect(driver='{SQL Server}', server='servername', 
database='dbname', trusted_connection='yes', autocommit=True)
cursor=conn.cursor()
a=cursor.execute(stmt)
cursor.commit()
conn.commit()
#cursor.close()
#conn.close()
```

Comment: The problem is almost certainly within the proc itself, which we can't see here. See if you can narrow that down beyond "a long one doesn't work and a short one does". Can you remove specific parts from the long one and make it work? Can you remove a bunch of the long one *and still have it not work*? (Alternately, maybe the proc can't correctly handle certain data in the *table*? What happens if you try running it directly from an SQL console?)

Comment: Make sure the proc includes `SET NOCOUNT ON` at the beginning. The row count messages (DONe_IN_PROC) can interfere with multi-statement processing in the app is not coded to handle multiple result sets.

Comment: Karl - The proc works completely fine when I execute in MS SQL Server, and yes if I narrow down that proc to fewer lines then its running completely fine when called from python. But this doesn't solve my purpose as narrowing down the proc removes essential functionality.

Dan - I have added SET NOCOUNT ON already but still I face the same issue

Comment: What is happening in the code which causes problem? Some data modification depending on the arguments passed to this SP? Run `sqlserver profiler` to check what's going on: are all of the arguments passed well, are there any exceptions.

Comment: Ivan - yes all the arguments are passed well but still the proc is not failing / completing. It just ends after about 2/3 rd completion and this is not the case when I run the same proc using SQL